# Is it possible to paint with materials as palette?

Tags: vertex-paint

I have a situation where it could be a practical approach to assign several materials to a mesh and use these materials as a palette so that we could paint the mesh faces with it.

The only way I found to do that is (of course) using edit mode, selecting the faces and assign them to the wanted material.

But this is not a very natural way to paint.

Is there a possible way to do that (no texture, just painting the faces) ?

Note : I needed to add a tag but the tag is not good here.

Comment: "Painting" without any texture and with possibility to control materials' distribution probably is possible only with vertex colors as you indicated with tag. That paint will depend on vertex count and topology though.

Comment: @MrZak, yes. But I wanted to paint faces with material (not with colors)... so impossible, I guess ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you're searching in the right way; materials will depend on any paint, either it's a texture, or vertex colors or whatever; but to use it you'll use 2 shaders affecting factor of their mixing. I don't *think* you can paint from the beginning *only* with material, because it doesn't seem to work like that. Btw, what's the render engine and what's the purpose of your painting ? (maybe it can be solved in another way).

Comment: @MrZak, I was just searching for a 'paint like style' of assigning materials to faces. An alternative to select/assign which can be done in edit mode. No more. So in that idea, not dependent of the render engine as long as things are visible in material or render mode.

Comment: As @MrZak already said, a possible way could be to use a texture as a mask. You can stack several "pass through" node for each color. Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kIdAq9wRoYM

Comment: Is the blender internal, or cycles?

Comment: @ARadish, basically Cycles but as is it finally simply a face to material assignation I hoped that could be for both

Comment: Hmm, well in BI, you have the material node, and you can bind materials to a color ramp and then to vertex colors, so that you can paint materials on... It's nifty, but i have no material node in cycles. :P o well

Comment: @Carlo, interesting technique, thanks. But this is not the aim. The idea is to paint/assign 1 material for 1 face (or painting on several faces to assign this material). Exactly the same result as assigning faces to a material in edit mode, but in a painting way