# Any way to use procedural material/textures for painting?

Tags: procedural

I am quite familiar with Blender (V2.81) and now I am starting to experiment with procedural material, made in the material node editor.

Now, I know that I can assign different materials to single faces of my object.
So a cube, up to 6 different materials (one for each surface).

But, is there any way to reuse that procedural material to **paint** on an object?
I really would like to use different procedural materials to blend together without using Image Textures (pixel graphics).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49914/smooth-transition-between-2-materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58938/is-it-possible-to-paint-with-materials-as-palette

Comment: You create a new Texture and UV that acts as a mask. You Paint Black and White on to this Texture and use it as the Factor with a Mix Node to combine your Materials. You can do this multiple times and you can paint with Alpha rather than B/W if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. How to tag my question with "answered"?